How to debug/analyze a slow zsh prompt (oh-my-zsh)?
I'm using oh-my-zsh, and it used to work well until yesterday.
Today, the prompt itself is incredibly slow: When I type a character it can take over a second until it appears on the screen (and the same for deleting characters). There is no load on the system that would explain the behavior.
Note: I'm not referring to the initial loading of the shell, but really just typing things in the prompt.
How can one narrow down the cause of such a problem? I.e., where would you start looking to get insight what is so slow here, for instance:

Are there any "tracing" logs with timing information that could indicate what the prompt is doing internally?
Are there any oh-my-zsh update logs that could explain what has changed from yesterday to today to possible blame a certain update?
Is there a good way to selectively enabled/disable certain zsh features/modules to isolate the issue?


This question is obviously related to this one. However, the answers in that question didn't help me so far, and I figured it is more useful to ask for "where to start looking" instead of "guess what my issue is".

How to troubleshoot?  The first step would be to remove your customizations and see if the stock OMZ exhibits the slowness.

Pedantic: Your prompt isn't slow.  The command line editor is slow.  If your prompt was slow, you'd have a huge delay after hitting return with no command, but no delay while typing.  Make sure you're debugging the right problem.  :)
